# defect in dojo/request/iframe for reading xml response

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

I am using dojo/request/iframe to do file upload. The file is uploaded fine, but when I am trying to get the response in XML, I always get this error (I tried in FF):

"TypeError: xmlText is undefined"

I have set the handleAs property to "xml" and based on the documentation of dojo/request/iframe, for responses in xml and html I don't need the response to be inside  tag. I used Firebug and I can see that my response is in xml format.

I have read a post about the possibility of this become a defect from dojo library, but there's no follow up on this: http://grokbase.com/p/dojo/dojo-checkins/12c7qyynnx/dojo-toolkit-16440-dojo-request-iframe-js-xmltext-is-undefined-error-in-ff-and-ie9

Does anybody know if this is actually a defect from Dojo? and is there any workaround? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But maybe it's misleading: The response, your xmlText is no Text, but an object. For me something like

```
    iframe(myForm.action, {
        handleAs: "html",
        data: data
    }).then(function(xmldoc){
        require(["dojo/dom-construct"],function(domConst){
            var new_elem = query("#"+myid,xmldoc)[0];
            if(new_elem)
               domConst.place(new_elem, elem, "replace");
            });
    }, function(err){
            // Handle the error condition
    });
```

did work fine.